# Opensource reporting services?

Tags: open-source, reporting-services

Are there any free and opensource **reporting services** which we can deploy in a web server, and which wouldn't require any licensing. Actually I'd be interested in the whole framework/toolkit, report designing, viewing, and hosting. It should be able to pull data from mssql database servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **JasperForge projects** (JasperReports, iReports, etc) at http://jasperforge.org/ I think is one of the most used plataform for reporting in Java projects.

Also check this comprehensive [**list of Java open source resources for reporting**](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting). Includes short descriptions for

- JFreeChart
- BIRT
- jCharts
- Cewolf
- JCCKit
- JChart2d
- DocumentBurster
- SWTJasperViewer
- iReport
- JasperReports
- JOpenChart
- Chart2D
- JFreeReport
- Datavision
- ART
- Open Reports
- Pentaho - Business Intelligence
- JMagallanes
- FreeReportBuilder
- OpenReports
- OpenI
- JGraphT
- prefuse
- QN Plot

Answer (score 1):

The open source [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/products/) suite includes a report server. I believe it's Java-based, so will connect to any datasource for which JDBC drivers are available (including SQL Server).

[SQL Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336&displaylang=en) includes a free version of SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: Yep, MSSQL Express w/ Advanced Services is free, but not open source.  It has some limitations, like not being able to schedule reports, and data must be stored in the local instance.  With Express you're also limited to using 1 CPU, 1 GB RAM, and 4 GB database size.  It works for me, but can get slow if you throw a lot of inserts at it.