# Excel automation from database, what's the Best Technology to do that?

Tags: .net, excel, msbuild, mono, nant

I want to have Excel reports generated from the database.

```
What do you think is the best Technology to use for Excel automation ?

Consider :
> Full Excel API Support is a must.
> Cross Platform solution preferable.
> Programmer's efficiency is high priority.
> Mono development is welcome, if that provides an edge.
> Open Source solutions are welcomed.
> VB.Net, C#.Net or something else ?
> What build environment to use, MSBuild or NAnt or something else ?
```

Please throw your experiences and advises for my project !!

Its going to be massive reporting project, with a lots of Excel API's to be exploited.

Comment: What hooks are you going to use into the Excel API? And in what forms is that available for cross-platform usage?

Comment: I will have to generate massively sized Excel reports with huge amount of data, it will include Graphs generation with AutoFilters,etc.

I want it work on all platforms to free it from the Microsoft World and avoid license fees.

Comment: So you want to generate Excel files, with support for a full Excel API, but keep it free, cross-platform and without Microsoft? You do realize that the Excel format itself is licensed by Microsoft, right?

Comment: Ya.. the excel format is Microsoft licensed but you don't need a license to generate excel files. My clients will need MS Office license to consume the reports. Plus Microsoft implementations are very inefficient, though it features the full API (Obviously). Then, You pay to use Windows, You pay for development and then pay to consume the development.. isn't that a loot ?

Comment: **Wait** for few more years then, OpenSource will have better implementations of Microsoft API's and for free.. That time is not so far.

Comment: I'm not questioning your goal - I'm questioning your requirements. "Full Excel API Support is a must" is hard to combine with "Cross Platform solution" and "free [...] from the Microsoft World and avoid license fees". But I think you should take a look at OpenOffice, see if they have an API that's good enough to start with and that can save in Excel format. It should be able to satisfy all your needs.

Comment: Thanks.. for the suggestion.. I know that full API support is difficult out of the microsoft world, But that's why I asked it here to find out if someone has figured out a way to do it.
Though I can-not use the open-office solution since my clients have ms office !

Comment: OpenOffice has the capability to save in .xls and (I believe) .xlsx formats as well, so you'll probably be able to output files readable in MS Excel from OO. However, you (and perhaps your management) should re-evaluate these specs and compare them to the real world. I can more or less promise you that you will not find a solution that meets *all* of your requirements.

Comment: Ya, I was not expecting much with this Question. But, OpenOffice is an implementation of Excel API's. They probably use their own. I don't think that they provide APIs as well for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has lots of technical requirements but not any business requirements, If the users want some reports from a DB that they can view / manipulate in excel then there are probably better ways to do it than using the excel API.

If you want to generate reports I'd suggest using something built for the job rather than implementing your own solution. If your SQL environment is MS SQL Server then SSRS would do the job, in fact you can use SSRS with other Databases if you want including mySQL and Oracle. If not then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537460/opensource-reporting-services/1537662#1537662) has some open source solutions.

Comment: **Thanks**, I didn't thought it this way. I will explore these as well. Anyways, my requirement is to generate Excel Files as reports after some processing over data fetched from the database.