# How can we dynamically generate certificates?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am designing a self service portal website for the conference held at my University.[ICDCIT](http://www.icdcit.ac.in/) Certificates are given to participants,authors and delegates attending the conference.So I need to dynamically generate their certificates which they can print in pdf format.[image: Example Certificate]. How should I do it? Is there any way or will I have to generate a HTML page with their names like that in edX Certificate?

Comment: Frontend : JQuery,CSS,HTML,Javascript Backend:Python with Flask and Heroku Database:postgres SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it in the HTML

> (Or generating the UI with using the Jquery - one way)

you can use

> SSRS Prints

or

> Crystal reports

implemetation.
SSRS Will be more easy for creating the pdf files dynamically according the dynamic data.

Comment: is there any open source library or software? Crystal reports is from SAP and SSRS Prints from Microsoft.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537460/opensource-reporting-services